# Typings of class overloading another class attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, python-asyncio, python-typing

I'm trying to create a class that calls another class attributes using `__getattr__` in order to wrap the class calls.

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager


class SessionThrottler:

    def __init__(self, session: ClientSession,
                 time_period: int, max_tasks: int):
        self._obj = session
        self._bucket = AsyncLeakyBucket(max_tasks=max_tasks,
                                        time_period=time_period)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        @asynccontextmanager
        async def _do(*args, **kwargs):
            async with self._bucket:
                res = await getattr(self._obj, name)(*args, **kwargs)
                yield res
        return _do

    async def close(self):
        await self._obj.close()
```

So then I can do:

```
async def fetch(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.get('http://localhost:5051') as resp:
        _ = resp


session = ClientSession()
session_throttled = SessionThrottler(session, 4, 2)
await asyncio.gather(
    *[fetch(session_trottled) 
      for _ in range(10)]
)
```

This code works fine but how can I do so that `session_throttled` is inferred as a `ClientSession` instead of `SessionThrottler` (kinda like `functools.wraps`) ?

Comment: With "inferred", do you mean that ``typing`` related tools such as mypy should think ``session_throttled`` is of type ``ClientSession``? Otherwise, what else do you mean by it? What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: /me facepalms - @MisterMiyagi that is likely what is desired - after I went through some really deep language meddling to make the wrapped instances to behave as desired. I added that to a session in my answer now.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on what you need with  "is inferred as".

## Making ThrotledSessions instances of ClientSessions

The natural way of doing that with classes is trough inheritance - if your `SessionThrotler` inherits from `ClientSession`, it would be naturally *be* a `ClientSession` as well.
The "small downside" is that then `__getattr__` would not work as expected, since  is only called for attributes not found in the instance - and Python would "see" the original methods from `ClientSession` in your ThrotledSession object and call those instead.

Of course, that would also require you to statically inherit your class, and you may want it to work dynamically. (by statically, I mean
having to write `class SessionThrotler(ClientSession):` - or at least, if there is a finite number of different Session classes you want to wrap, write for each a subclass inheriting from ThrotledClass as well:

```py
class ThrotledClientSession(ThrotledSession, ClientSession):
    ...
```

If that is something that would work for you, then it is a matter of fixing attribute access by creating `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`. The difference between both is that `__getattribte__` emcompasses *all* of the attribute lookup steps, and is called at the beggning of the lookup. Whereas `__getattr__` is called as part of the normal lookup (inside the standard algorithm for `__getattribute__`) when all else fails.

```py
class SessionThrottlerMixin:

    def __init__(self, session: ClientSession,
                 time_period: int, max_tasks: int):
        self._bucket = AsyncLeakyBucket(max_tasks=max_tasks,
                                        time_period=time_period)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if not name.startswith("_") or not callable(attr):
             return attr
        @asynccontextmanager
        async def _do(*args, **kwargs):
            async with self._bucket:
                res = await attr(*args, **kwargs)
                yield res
        return _do

    class ThrotledClientSession(SessionThrottlerMixin, ClientSession):
        pass
```

If  you are getting your `CLientSession` instances from other code, and don't want, or can't, replace the base class with this one, you can do that on the desired instances, by assigning to the `__class__` attribute: 
it works if `ClientSession` is a normal Python class, not inheriting from special bases like Python built-ins, not using `__slots__` and a few other restrictions - the instance is "converted" to a `ThrotledClientSession` midflight (but you have to do the inheritance thing): `session.__class__ = ThrottledClientSession`.

Class assignemnt in this way won't run the new class `__init__`. Since you need the `_bucket` to be created, you could have a class method that would create the bucket and make the replacement - so, in the version with `__getattribute__` add something like:

```py
class SessionThrottler:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def _wrap(cls, instance, time_period: int, max_tasks: int):
       cls.__class__ = cls
       instance._bucket = AsyncLeakyBucket(max_tasks=max_tasks,
                                            time_period=time_period)
       return instance 

    ...

throtled_session = ThrotledClientSession._wrap(session, 4, 2)
```

If you have a lot of parent classes that you want to wrap this way, and you don't want to declare a `Throttled`version of it, this *could* be made dynamically - but I would only go that way if it were the only way to go. Declaring some 10 stub Thotled versions, 3 lines each, would be preferable.

## Virtual Subclassing

If you can change the code of your `ClientSession` classes (and others you want to wrap) this is the least obtrusive way -

Python have an obscure OOP feature called `Virtual Subclassing` in which a class can be registered as a subclass of another, without real inheritance. However, the class that is to be the "parent" have to have `abc.ABCMeta`  as its metaclass - otherwise this is really unobtrusive.

Here is how it works:

```py
In [13]: from abc import ABC                                                                                                         

In [14]: class A(ABC): 
    ...:     pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                             

In [15]: class B:  # don't inherit
    ...:     pass

In [16]: A.register(B)                                                                                                               
Out[16]: __main__.B

In [17]: isinstance(B(), A)                                                                                                          
Out[17]: True
```

So, in your original code, if you can make `ClientSession` to inherit from `abc.ABC` (without any other change *at all*) - and then do:

`ClientSession.register(SessionThrottler)`
and it would just work (if the "inferred as" you mean has to do with the object type).

Note that if ClientSession and others have a different metaclass, adding `abc.ABC` as one of its bases will fail with a metaclass conflict. If you can change their code, this is *still* the better way to go: just create a collaborative metaclass that inherits from both metaclasses, and you are all set:

```py
class Session(metaclass=IDontCare):
    ...


from abc import ABCMeta

class ColaborativeMeta(ABCMeta, Session.__class__):
    pass

class ClientSession(Session, metaclass=ColaborativeMeta):
    ...
```

## Type hinting

If you don't need "isinstance" to work, and just have to be the same for the typing system, then it is just a matter of using `typing.cast`:

```
import typing as T
...
session = ClientSession()
session_throttled = T.cast(ClientSession, SessionThrottler(session, 4, 2))
```

The object is untouched at runtime - just the same object, but from that point on, tools like `mypy` will consider it to be an instance of `ClientSession`.

## Last, but not least, change the class name.

So, if by "inferred as" you don't mean that the wrapped class should be seen as an instance, but just care about the class name showing correctly in logs and such, you can just set the class `__name__` attribute to whatever string you want:

```py
class SessionThrottler:
    ...

SessionThrottelr.__name__ = ClientSession.__name__
```

Or just have an appropriate `__repr__` method on the wrapper class:

```py
class SessionThrottler:
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on patching the object methods (instead of wrapping them) given to the context manager.

```
import asyncio
import functools
import contextlib

class Counter:
    async def infinite(self):
        cnt = 0
        while True:
            yield cnt
            cnt += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

def limited_infinite(f, limit):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def inner(*a, **kw):
        cnt = 0
        async for res in f(*a, **kw):
            yield res
            if cnt == limit:
                break
            cnt += 1
    return inner

@contextlib.contextmanager
def throttler(limit, counter):
    orig = counter.infinite
    counter.infinite = limited_infinite(counter.infinite, limit)
    yield counter
    counter.infinite = orig

async def main():
    with throttler(5, Counter()) as counter:
        async for x in counter.infinite():
            print('res: ', x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

For your case the it means patching every relevant methods of `ClientSession`(http methods only probably). Not sure if it is better though.